# ZipArchive memory problems on iPhone for large archive

Tags: iphone, php-ziparchive

I am trying to compress multiple files into a single zip archive and I am running into low memory warning. Since the complete zip file is loaded into the memory I guess that's the problem. Is there a way by which I can manage the compression/decompression better using ZipArchive so that not all the data is in the memory at once?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the exact same problem. It would be great if you can tell us if you were able to resolve this issue. Thanks!!

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some investigation on alternatives to ZipArchive I found another project called Objective-zip that seems to be a little better than ZipArchive. Here is the link:

http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/

The API is quite simple. One thing I ran into was that in the begging I was reading data and never releasing it so if you are adding a bunch of large files to the zip file remember to release the data. Here is a little code I used:

```
ZipFile *zipFile = [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:archivePath mode:ZipFileModeCreate];

for(NSString *path in subpaths){
  NSData *data= [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:longPath];
  ZipWriteStream *stream = [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:path compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelNone];
  [stream writeData:data];
  [stream finishedWriting];
  [data release];
}

[zipFile close];
[zipFile release];
```

I hope this is helpful for anyone who runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to deal with this is to simply change ZipArchive's method of reading the file into the NSData. Just change the following code

```
data = [ NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file ];
```

to

```
data = [ NSData dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:file ];
```

That will cause the OS to read the file in a memory mapped way. Basically it just uses way less memory as it reads from the file as it needs to rather than loading it all into memory at once.

Comment: will this support reading files of unlimited size, or does it just use less memory (but still have limitations)?

Comment: I haven't done any extensive testing with it, but I've compressed zip files in my app which end up being a few hundred megabytes.